# One Visual Studio 2017 Solution, two git repos. How to manage?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have a Windows application which is a git repo, the VS Solution comprises two projects

1. The Windows application
2. Class library

The class library is a common/shared project used by many of our solutions and is in its own git repository, i.e. added to the solution via 'add existing project' and so all that is in this windows application folder is itself and the .sln file has a reference to the class library.

In my Windows application everything for git solely points to the windows application, so if I make changes to the class library, I have to remember to either open the class library separately in another instance of Visual Studio (use switch using the connections option in team explorer) or manually at the command line update this.

I was hoping there would be a way in visual studio (I'm using 2017) for it to allow me to manage both at once, i.e. the 'team explorer' could manage them separately, as it kind of makes complete sense that solutions make use of multiple separate projects and would want to do this.

I can't find any, other than manually switch. Any ideas?

If this is supported in 2019 it can be an avenue I explore but I'd still like any information on 2017.

thanks.

Comment: This isn't a Visual Studio problem, it's a patterns/practices problem. Turn the shared component into a NuGet package. Reference it as a package reference. Update it to publish the package to a local package repository after building.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but you're saying that when you are modifying a project and happen to find bugs in a shared library that you want to update there and then, you should'nt allow yourself to even see the code and instead log an issue, and fix it separately in a new dev cycle? and of course set up our own little nuget package repository...

Comment: Absolutely. When you make a change to a shared component, you need to either allow consumers to opt in to newer versions, or **fully regression test** every consumer of that component to ensure you didn't break anything.

Comment: Hello, I've just found EZ-GIT in the marketplace, with a click of a button you can switch repos, so a lot simpler than the current, but still doesn't support both at once. Maybe this will suffice... Remember though, not every solution requires this level of control, it might be just a single person with their own little helper libraries for their own use...